# How do I prove this isomorphism $D_{4n}\cong D_{2n}\,\times\, Z_2$ if $n\geq 3$ as an odd integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $n$ is an odd and positive integer, show that $D_{4n}\cong D_{2n}\,\times\, Z_2$. Denote that $D_{2n}$ is the Dihedral Groups with $2n$ elements and $Z_2$ is a cyclic group with order 2. I think it might be solved by using the recognizing theorem.

Comment: This is going to be difficult, because it's false. For instance, $D_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Then what if $n\geq3$?

Comment: Try to look at the maximal order of an element in $D_{4n}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is false efor every $n$. Since every dihedral $D_{2n}$ has a cyclic subgroup of maximal order $2n$,  $D_{2n} \times Z_2$ has the its biggest cyclic group of the same order, while $D_{4n}$ has a cyclic subgroup  of order $4n$.

Comment: If we can find $D_{4n}=HK$ where $H, K$ are normal subgroups of $D_{4n}$ satisfying $H\cong D_{2n}$ and $K\cong Z_2$, $H\cap K=e$?

Comment: @廖倪徵 You won’t be able to; you can find such groups, but not both normal. $H$ will be normal (index $2$), but you won’t find a normal complement. It just *isn’t true* except for the dihedral group of order $4$.